# Groovy - execute ssh and provide password

Tags: groovy, ssh

I know that there are `AntBuilder` and `JSch`, etc. but I want do something like this - without any dependencies:

```
def sshArray = ["ssh root@11.11.11.11 -p 111 '/etc/init.d/tomcat7 stop'", ...]

def env = System.getenv().collect { k,v -> "$k=$v" }

sshArray.each {
    println "Executing: " + it
    def process = (it).execute(env, null)
    def writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(process.out))
    writer.println("mypassword")
    writer.close()
    process.waitFor()
    process.consumeProcessOutput(System.out, System.err)
}
```

But this sadly doesn't work, because the output I'm getting is:

```
Executing: ssh root@11.11.11.11 -p 111 '/etc/init.d/tomcat7 stop'
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
...
```

Moreover, I'm getting the same output if I comment out these lines:

```
def writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(process.out))
writer.println("mypassword")
writer.close()
```

Why am I getting "Permission denied" 3 times? How can I provide password to ssh process?
Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think the published script does nearly what you were thinking. 
def writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(process.out)) will give you the output stream of the process. and after that you put your password to that writer, but it is nowhere connected to the process output that way (and even then, it would be wrong since you would post to the output of the process)

Answer (score 4):

Programs like ssh generally don't read the password from their standard input; they read it directly from the terminal.  Java and groovy don't provide any way control the terminal.

This isn't a problem with ssh or Java: passwords are meant to be entered by a person.  If your program needs to use ssh, the proper way to use it is with key-based authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I think what you're doing is starting a process and then CONSUMING its output (process.out). You should be feeding the input to the process. It should be the **InputStream** you're dealing with.